# Timing of async callback

Tags: ios

I want to have a better idea about the timing of the completion block from a intenet download request. In this case firebase. The following code example does not do anything, but it illustrates my questions.

Say I have 100 values in keysArray, there would be 100 async request to firebase and the completion block will be executed 100 times

```
func someFunction() {
    for keys in keysArray {
        loadDataFromFirebaseWithKey(completionHandler: { (success, data) in

            print(data)

            // Task A Some length for loop
            for i in 0...10000 {
                print("A")
            }

            // Task B
            for i in 10001...20000 {
                print("B")
            }
        })

        // Task C
        for i in 20001...30000 {
            print("C")
        }

        // Task D
        for i in 30001...40000 {
            print("D")
        }
    }
    // Task E
    for i in 40001...50000 {
        print("E")
    }

    // Task F
    for i in 50001...60000 {
        print("F")
    }
}
```

The reason I am using such a big for loop is to illustrate some time consuming/non async proccess. Here are three case that I was wondering

1. Say if the program is half way through task C, does it finish C and also D before going into the completion block to do A and B
2. Say if the program is half way through task E, does it finish E and also F before going into the completion block to do A and B

Comment: You have those results out right, I meant you are printing everything. So, ideally you should see the results.

Comment: Instead of posting this question, why not actually do the test? What results do you get? Based on the results, if you don't understand those results, update your question to ask about why the results come out differently than you expected.

Comment: I appreciate the reasoning behind the "did you try it?" advice, but would be wary of advising that empirical evidence should be determinative when we're talking about concurrency. It's contractual guarantees that matter, not whether you happen to hit the one-in-a-thousand race condition during development.

Comment: If the completion block is run on the main thread, then yes, if C or E has started, it will finish all of C&D or E&F, respectively, before running A&B. If, on the other had, the completion block is run on some background thread, then A&B won't wait. IIRC, Firebase runs its completion handlers on the main thread, in which case it will not run A&B concurrently with respect to C&D or E&F.

Comment: Thanks @Rob and Tommy. That clears it. So basically, in the case of the function being on main thread, the completion block gets executed immediately when it sees "}" that was from a higher level I presume? I was not able to "try" the code and get a full understanding because the internet speed, processing power (where the code might be at) are factors that are hard to control to allow me to get the full insight of what should happen in all cases.

Comment: Re: "the completion block gets executed immediately when it sees '}' that was from a higher level I presume" ... I would rephrase that: The completion block gets queued when the asynchronous Firebase task finishes (which may be immediately, it more likely will be just a bit later). And in term of when that queued block runs, it's a question of when (a) whatever is running on the main thread has finished; and (b) any other prior tasks that were queued for the main queue have also finished.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tasks are running concurrently, they may replace each other as the active thing at an opportunity, and may just proceed with genuine concurrency given that all iOS devices since the 4s have multiple cores. There's no reason that any particular `for` loop will be at any specific point at the time of interruption.

If Firebase schedules its completion handlers on a serial queue then none of the handlers will overlap with any other.

If Firebase schedules its completion handlers on the main queue, and you're calling it from the main queue, neither its completion handlers nor your calling code will overlap with each other.

So, directly to answer:

1. yes if Firebase is scheduling completion handlers on the same queue as you called from and that queue is serial — which almost always means 'yes' if everything is main queue linked. Otherwise no.
2. same answer. There's no special concurrency magic to `for` loops. They're exactly as usurpable as any other piece of code.

Comment: Thanks Tommy. Great explanation from you and Rob in relation to concurrency